# Adding two vectors coerced from logical to numeric

Tags: r

In the example below, the logical vectors `!is.na(X)` and `!is.na(Y)` are coerced to numeric by pre-multiplying by an integer, and then added. But the result looks as if "+" is being interpreted as XOR. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
set.seed(1)
X <- sample(c(NA,1),10,replace=T)
Y <- sample(c(NA,1),10,replace=T)

2*!is.na(X)                # numeric, as expected
#  [1] 0 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 0
2*!is.na(Y)                # numeric, as expected
#  [1] 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 2 0 2
2*!is.na(X) + 2*!is.na(Y)  # huh?
#  [1] 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 2 0

# but this works...
xx <- 2*!is.na(X)
yy <- 2*!is.na(Y)
xx+yy
#  [1] 0 0 4 2 2 2 4 4 2 2

# as does this...
as.numeric(2*!is.na(X)) + 2*!is.na(Y)
#  [1] 0 0 4 2 2 2 4 4 2 2

# and this...
2*(!is.na(X)) + 2*(!is.na(Y))
#  [1] 0 0 4 2 2 2 4 4 2 2
```

Run in a fresh session. R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06), Win 7 x64

Comment: Two words: operator precedence.

Comment: Clue: `2*!is.na(X) + 3*!is.na(Y)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you were expecting:

```
 (2*!is.na(X)) + (2*!is.na(Y))
 #[1] 0 0 4 2 2 2 4 4 2 2
```

Yours was being parsed like:

```
 2*!( is.na(X) + 2*!is.na(Y) )
 [1] 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 2 0
```